# Balancing Brackets Algorithm: Stack Data Structure

Tags: javascript, stack, balanced-delimiters

I am currently refining my understanding of data structures and as such, decided to implement a popular application of the *Stack*. Below you will find my implementation of the **Balancing Symbols** algorithm written in JavaScript.

My basic questions are:

- How clean would you rate my code?
- Is time complexity O(n): Linear?
- How can I improve?

```
function isBalanced(arr){
  var stack = new Stack();
  var last;

  arr.forEach(function(curr){
    if (curr === '(' || curr === '[' || curr === '{') {
      stack.push(curr);
    }

    if (curr === ')' || curr === ']' || curr === '}') {
      last = stack.peek() + curr;
      if (last === '()' || last === '[]' || last === '{}') {
        stack.pop();
      }
    }
  });

  var result = (stack.length() === 0) ?  true : false;
  console.log(result);
}

var symbols = ['{', '(', ')', ']'];

isBalanced(symbols);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks reasonably clean, IMO. I assume that it is purposely ES5?

I don't know about `Stack` as it's not a ES5 standard API (that I know of).

You are not returning any value.  There is no need for `? true : false` — just do `return stack.length() === 0;`.

Some code that you can consider, in ES5.

```js
var completes = ['()', '[]', '{}'];
var open = completes.map(function(complete) {
  return complete.charAt(0);
});
var close = completes.map(function(complete) {
  return complete.charAt(1);
});

function isBalanced(arr) {
  var stack = [];
  arr.forEach(function(curr) {
    if (open.indexOf(curr) !== -1) {
      stack.push(curr);
    }
    if (close.indexOf(curr) !== -1) {
      var last = stack.pop();
      if (completes.indexOf(last + curr) === -1) {
        stack.push(last);
      }
    }
  });
  return stack.length === 0;
}

console.log(isBalanced(['{', '(', ')', ']']));
console.log(isBalanced(['[', '(', ')', ']']));
```

Comment: Yes it is ES5 on purpose, I just wanted to get the concepts down rather than config my environment to execute ES6. Stack was a class that I created to mimic the functionality from other OOP languages.

Comment: I assume that `Stack` is pretty similar in functionality as the code in my example?

Comment: Yes, arrays in JS have almost identical functionality to the methods in my Stack class. You're solid.